# Retain the order of the list while using isin function in spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I’m using isin function in spark java and passing the list of id, **need to retrieve the id’s in the order of the list passed.** But Order is getting changed after using isin function,It is maintaining the order of Dataset.

How can I retain the order as in the list?

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJdbcDs").setMaster("local[*]"));
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("JavaTokenizerExample").getOrCreate();

RowFactory.create("405-048011-62815", "CRC Industries"),
                RowFactory.create("630-0746","Dixon value"),
                RowFactory.create("4444-444","3M INdustries"),
                RowFactory.create("4333-444","3M INdustries"),
                RowFactory.create("4777-444","3M INdustries"),
                RowFactory.create("4444-888","3M INdustries"),
                RowFactory.create("4999-444","3M INdustries"),
                RowFactory.create("5666-55","Dixon coupling valve"));

StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {new StructField("label1", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
        new StructField("sentence1", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()) });

Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);

List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
listStrings.add("5666-55");
listStrings.add("630-0746");
listStrings.add("4777-444");
listStrings.add("4444-444");


Dataset<Row> matchFound1=sentenceDataFrame.filter(col("label1").isin(listStrings.stream().toArray(String[]::new)));
matchFound1.show();
```

Current output:

```
+--------+--------------------+

|  label1|           sentence1|

+--------+--------------------+

|630-0746|         Dixon value|

|4444-444|       3M INdustries|

|4777-444|       3M INdustries|

| 5666-55|Dixon coupling valve|

+--------+--------------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+--------+--------------------+

|  label1|           sentence1|

+--------+--------------------+

| 5666-55|Dixon coupling valve|

|630-0746|         Dixon value|

|4777-444|       3M INdustries|

|4444-444|       3M INdustries|

+--------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Some options 1) sort the DataFrame by the label. 2) do a join instead, may also need to do #1 still. Performance at scale can be much better especially when using the sql.functions.broadcast join hint. 3) NOT ok with large DF, but you could collectAsList and make the match that way. 4) map over the values, find matches and create new list/DF with only those matched records. 5) sort the partition (and explicitly make only 1 for testing of this theory) then do your match. On phone, so I can't test my suggestions properly ATM

Comment: Not able to sort because lable has hyphens(-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a `dataframe` instead of `list` and join with `sentenceDataFrame`, you will retain the order aswell. This is more effective then creating `list` and `filtering`.